# crash while compiling opencv

Tags: 14.04, crash, opencv

I'm currently trying to install opencv-3.0.0 on ubuntu 14.04 as per these instructions:

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html

Everything works fine until I have to run the make command. It gets to around 33% done and then my computer crashes.
I'm new to ubuntu and don't really know how to go about troubleshooting this problem. I'm assuming it's got something to do with the hardware I'm using and not necessarily the os. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Your link is broken. Clicking it gives 404.

Comment: seems like it works now. in the source files, look for configure.log and the word "Error"

Comment: I managed to get it to compile and install in a virtual console. Still would like to know why I can't do it in the X terminal. Is it just too cpu intensive to compile very large binaries in a GUI?

Answer (score 1):

Your CPU is probably overheating. It was crashing for me too when I was compiling it using 4 cores `make -j 4`, once I used only a single core `make -j 1`, the compilation completed successfully.